# Count distinct date occurrences for each id in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Considering this DataFrame:

```
id     date
837    2016-12-01
837    2016-12-01
840    2016-12-01
840    2016-12-01
840    2016-12-01
837    2016-12-02
837    2016-12-02
837    2016-12-02
841    2016-12-02
841    2016-12-02
837    2016-12-03
837    2016-12-03
841    2016-12-03
```

What is the best way to compute the following result:

```
id     number_of_distinct_dates
837    3
840    1
841    2
```

Explanation: for each `id`, compute the number of distinct `date` on which it appears, and put the results in a new DataFrame. Here, `837` appears on 3 distinct dates, `840` appears only on a single date and `841` appears on 2 distinct dates.

I tried to play with `DataFrame.groupby()` but so far the closest I've been able to come up with is:

```
id     date
837    2016-12-01    2
       2016-12-02    3
       2016-12-03    2
840    2016-12-01    3
841    2016-12-02    2
       2016-12-02    1
```

By using `df.groupby(['id','date']).size()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` with [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html), last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (df.groupby('id')['date'].nunique())
id
837    3
840    1
841    2
Name: date, dtype: int64

print (df.groupby('id',)['date'].nunique().reset_index(name='number_of_distinct_dates'))
    id  number_of_distinct_dates
0  837                         3
1  840                         1
2  841                         2
```